# Specific temperature ranges of kinetic combustion mechanisms

Tags: kinetics, combustion, chemical-engineering

Do kinetic combustion mechanisms typically operate within specific temperature ranges? I tested some mechanisms from the scientific literature, and apparently they were only working at temperatures greater than 1000 K. Is this common to happen or am I probably making an error in my tests?

Comment: related https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/16664/what-is-the-lower-bound-to-the-temperature-at-which-a-fire-can-burn